# Join Multiple tables using SQL

Tags: sql, join, append

I'm a relative newbie to SQL, I'm trying to join data from 4 tables

- Table 1 (Main Data source) Join on ID
- Table 2 (Secondary data source) left join on table 1.ID
- Table 3 (Main Data source - archived data) Join on ID
- Table 4 (Secondary data source - archived data) left join on table 3.ID

Essentially tables 1 & 3 hold the same/similar data as do tables 2 & 4
So I think I need;

- Table 1 appending to table 3
- Table 2 appending to table 4
- then a left join on ID?

Or

- left join tables 1 & 2
- Left join tables 3 & 4

then append together?

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Cheers
Nik

- I can successfully left join tables 1 & 2 and
  Left join tables 3 & 4, its the final step i'm struggling with

Comment: Sample data and desired results -- mocked up -- would really clarify what you want to do.

Comment: This is (obviously) (extremely) not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a (base or query result) relation(ship)/association or table, say what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table. See [ask], [mcve] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM t3
LEFT JOIN t4 on t3.id = t4.id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it didn't work at first using  select *, but was it worked fine when I named all columns.